# Every locally finite measure space is regular

Tags: measure-theory

> Prove that every locally finite measure space is regular.

I am not sure how to go about this problem. Certainly, this can be shown to be true for any ball of finite measure that is contained in a larger ball by local finiteness and continuity of finite measure from above and below, but how would I go about proving this for an arbitrary set $A$?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you got this problem from, but it seems to be false, see for example the third example from this section:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure#Inner_regular_measures_that_are_not_outer_regular

You have a locally finite measure there that is *inner-regular* but not *outer-regular*(and hence not regular).